# Active Directory как проверить пароль для пользоваетяля

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Целевая среда - Линукс. Используется библиотека "[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement)".

Подскадите как проверить пару логин и пароль для пользователя ? Для подключения использую класс "LdapConnection".

```
using var conn = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("IP", port));
conn.Bind(new NetworkCredential("ldapsearch", "password"));
```

как найти польователя уже разобрался, однако пароль не возвращается. Возможно есть какой то отдельный запрос для проверки пароля ?

Когда вместо "ldapsearch" подставляю пользователя которого нужно проверить, то пишет что credentials не верны. Однако я ввожу точно корректную пару логин / пароль.

Возможно нужно как то настроить пользователя что бы иметь возможность авторизоваться через LDAP ? Или же есть какой то иной способ проверки ?

В нтернете есть примеры использования объекта "DirectoryContext" и вызов метода "FindOne", однако мне это не подзодит так как данный подход поддерживается только для Windows.

Comment: Для линукс использовал Novel.Directory.Ldap, чтобы убрать зависимость от Windows. Там только один минус, если нужен SID, то его придется конвертировать к привычному представлению, а в остальном плюс-минус одно и то же.

Comment: ну и да, пароль и не будет возвращаться, он хранится в AD с необратимым шифрованием, так что проверка корректности пары логин-пароль только путем попытки логина в AD. Имя пользователя при этом указывать полное, с именем домена

Comment: @rdorn попробую, спасибо.